# How to run automated tests in Github actions for Kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, github, automated-tests, github-actions

Language: Kotlin,
my build.yml file is:

```
name: Build

on:
    push:
        branches: [main]
    pull_request:
        branches: [main]

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest


        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v2
          - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
            with:
              java-version: '11'
              distribution: 'adopt'
          - name: Validate Gradle wrapper
            uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@e6e38bacfdf1a337459f332974bb2327a31aaf4b
          - name: Run the Gradle package task
            uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@937999e9cc2425eddc7fd62d1053baf041147db7

          - name: Grant Permissions to gradlew
            run: chmod +x gradlew
          - name: Test
            run: ./gradlew test
```

It sees the test file correctly. But there is a test that has to fail. Yet it successfully passes in GitHub actions. How can I run tests correctly in GitHub actions?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It does not run the tests. I want it to run all the tests after each push.

Comment: You can check out my setup in here, https://github.com/chenrui333/spring-boot-template/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml, you do not need to `chmod +x gradlew` though.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciating comment. I tried your setup in my repository but I got the same result. It passes where it should have failed. This is my repository: [link](https://github.com/socodes/blockchain_kt) . I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: Got you, let me check out your repo.

Comment: Filed a PR, https://github.com/socodes/blockchain_kt/pull/1

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i think it is not working again :(. For example, in the 2nd test, the answer should have been wrong, but I did true. However, the tests do not fail. Am I missing something, shouldn't Actions run the tests and return the result?

Comment: oh, you expect tests failed? I thought the issue was the tests failed to run, maybe i am wrong.

Comment: :) let me explain again. I want it to run all the tests on every push. If any test should fail, it should say tests failed. But if tests passes, it should say everything is fine.